# Javascript Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I need to get the value of below control using javascript.I am getting null every time I am using the below javascript code

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedVal2}" id="mychkbx" onchange="is_checked();" />
```

Javascript code used

```
 document.getElementById("{!$Component.surveypage.survey.answers2.mychkbx}")
```

Where,
surveypage=id of the page
survey=id of the form
answers2=page block table id
mychkbx=id of the input field.

Even when i am directly referencing the id of the field generated then also it is coming as null

Id generated

> document.getElementById("surveypage:survey:j_id28:j_id29:answers2:0:mychkbx")

Please let me know what needs to be done in this case or where I am doing wrong??

Comment: Can you please post the VF page code?

Comment: I can't post the code because of CDP constraints

Comment: `apex:pageBlockTable` adds a number for Id of each element in a row, for Visualforce components. (As you can see here - surveypage:survey:j_id28:j_id29:answers2:0:mychkbx). Accessing elements with jQuery is easier..

Comment: Even with Jquery also it is coming as null.I used $("# surveypage:survey:j_id28:j_id29:answers2:0:mychkbx")

Comment: I dont think it is easy to guess what happens inside your code. Try to use developer tools of your browser to figure out what is working and what is not

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be helpful if you post the full VF page to build the $component.... expression if we use javascript,

solution using jQuery is straight forward:

$j= jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(
function () {
$j('id$="mychkbx"').value();
}
);

Ps.. i am using handphone to type so syntax errors may be present